# Convenient method for frequent ssh

Tags: command-line, ssh

I frequently have to access the departmental servers while I'm off campus which requires:

```
ssh user@public.school.com
```

then enter password, then

```
ssh private.school.com
```

then enter same password again. (You can't ssh directly to the second one unless you're on the campus network.)

How can I make it so that I can just type a simple one-line command and get right into the private server? I'm not worried about security here at all, I'd really like to just skip having to type a password altogether.

Answer (score 2):

SSH allows you to specify a command to be run on the remote host in place of a login shell. Therefore, you can write an SSH command that chains together two instances, like so:

```
ssh user@public.school.com -t -t ssh user@private.school.com
```

Of course, you can leave out usernames if they're the same.

Obviously, this is a hassle to type, so you can set a bash alias by putting the following line in your `~/.bash_profile` file (you will need to create it if it does not already exist):

```
alias school_ssh='ssh user@public.school.com -t -t ssh user@private.school.com'
```

I don't think you can specify a password. However, if you can, you could generate an SSH key pair. On your local computer, put the private key, and put the public key on the public school network. Then ssh into the public network and generate a second keypair. Leave the second private key on the public network, and put the second public key on the private network.

SSH keys will ask you for a passphrase. You can specify none, by simply not typing anything at the generation prompt and hitting enter, but I would recommend against this. This is because SSH passphrases are less painful than just a regular password: when a program running in an xterm asks to use an SSH key, Ubuntu will pop up a graphical password box instead of asking you in the terminal. You then have the option to keep the SSH key unlocked for the rest of the session. You can also set Ubuntu to automatically unlock the key at login.

Comment: When I `ssh user@public.school.com ssh user@private.school.com` I'm prompted for the user@private password, but after I enter it it says:
`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).`

Comment: try running `ssh user@public.school.com -t -t ssh user@private.school.com'.

Comment: That works, but then I still have to enter the same password twice, so it doesn't save much time. Thanks anyways, I'll keep looking.

Comment: @Natalie like I said, this is the best that you can do - it's impossible to specify a password to use. Your best bet would be to use a public/private keypair.